# iPhone App launches from the last known state, instead of relaunching from beginning of process

Tags: ios, state

I am having difficulty with the development of a POC at work.

Currently the flow of my app is as follows: 
App launches,
Delegate instantiates a loading view, 
Loading view prompts user with an alert,
Alert accepted then the app switches to a registration view
Complete the registration process and save - writes details to file 
Switches to Add Attendance View
Record submitted, then home button pressed

When the app is launched again, 
The loading view should appear, then check for the existence of a settings file in the app bundle
If file is present - switch view directly to attendance view (user has already registered)
else switch to registration view.

However, when the app is relaunched it skips any loading screen, and goes directly to the attendace screen, which is a series of pre-populated textfields, none of which are pre-populated as required.

This appears to be an issue with the maintenance of the apps state post sending an attendance record.

I am not a native ios developer, and I am struggling to understand where I am going wrong, and help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote it would seem you are talking about application returning from background. Since you said you are not a native iOS developer, this is closer to minimizing a desktop application and then expand it again (all the threads are paused after some short time though). So yes, the application stays where you left it and nothing is reloaded.

Apple prepared a few methods usually located in application delegate class, for this case it would be `- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application`. Once this gets called you will have to reload application state.

Also there used to be parameter in "plist" where you could enable/disabled permission for the application to enter background. If you do not allow it to enter background it will close and will be forced to restart, fixing your problem. This though is not the most elegant solution and it might not even be allowed anymore.

Comment: So how would you propose I go about utilizing (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application, should I put the code to instantiate the first screen here? Or shold I call the method elsewhere ?

Comment: Well, at least some "refresh" method should be called to repopulate the text fields. It really depends on what you need to do.